# Bootstrap Select jump to typed in letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Hi Im using [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for a state dropdown and would like to implement the functionality where if a user starts typing "c" then it would drop them down to "california" (as an example). This is already out of the box for plugin but I would like to change where if the user "co" then it would drop them down to "Colorado", instead it takes them first to "california" after typing the "c" and then to "ohio" after typing the "o". Is there any way to accomplish this with the bootstrap select plugin?

FYI The plugin is pretty heavily incorporated into the site at the moment and changing to another plugin wouldnt really be an option for me.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2a9xp/513/

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({size:10});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>California</option>
  <option>Colorado</option>
  <option>Connecticut</option>
  <option>Kansas</option> 
  <option>Kentucky</option>
  <option>Ohio</option>
  <option>Oklahoma</option>
  <option>Oregon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i suggest using from this library https://select2.github.io/

Comment: Could you be missing data-live-search="true" attribute in your select tag

Comment: @PravinUmamaheswaran I dont necessarily want to filter the results just have them jump to the more relevant option

Comment: @hasanmovahed While this isnt a breaker for our project our deadline is coming up soon and changing to select2 presents too many unknowns

Answer (score 4):

add to select: **data-live-search-style="startsWith"**

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vvuhq53g/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any parent component in your project? in my case, this problem causes by select.min.js load every time i open component contains select box. So i move this lib to biggest component, make sure that this lib load only one time.